# Find unique columns with criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table that is written to by several external users. Each user has its own id and logs a single message at a time. Each row in this table has an auto-increment field called message_id. In other words, each row in the table has its own unique identifier. So if one were to sort the table by the message_id column, he would get all the messages sorted in chronological order.

Is there a single SQL command that can return the latest messages logged by each user?

I can do this in two steps:

1. Get a list of user_ids.
2. For each user_id:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM myTABLE AS T WHERE T.user_id=user_id 
   ORDER BY message_id DESC 
   LIMIT 1
   ```

But I think there is a better way.

Thanks

Comment: Doh... I could not think of the right words to search. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a `join` or a `where` condition:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id) from mytable t2 where t2.user_id = t.user_id);
```

For best performance, you want an index on `mytable(user_id, id)`.

Without such an index, you are possibly best off with an explicit `join`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t join
     (select max(id) as maxid
      from mytable t2
      group by user_id
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.maxid;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are trying to execute a single query that will grab a limited number of results for each `user_id`. I found this question which might be helpful.

[Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Edit: After studying this a bit more, it seems as if this is a complicated thing to achieve in MySQL. Unless you are struggling with ways to look for performance increases, I think you'd do just fine with a loop to query the table for each user you need data for. Of course, it depends on how much data you have and how many users there are.